# Testing CompletableFuture.supplyAsync with Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, completable-future

I am trying to test CompletableFuture.supplyAsync function with mockito but the test is not completing probably because the completable future is not returning. I am not sure what I am missing in the code. Can anyone please help.

I have written the code as follows.
So there are UserService class which returns User, UserEntityService class which returns users entities and a validation class to check if the entities belongs to the user or not.

I want to test if the passed entities belongs to user or not.

```
class UserService {

    CompletableFuture<User> getUser(String userName) {
        log.info("Fetching User with username {}", userName);
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> getUserByPortalUserName(userName));
    }
}
```

```
class UserEntityService {

    CompletableFuture<List<UserEntity>> getUserEntities(Long userId) {
        log.info("Retrieving all entities for user id {}", userId);
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> getAllByUserId(userId));
    }
}
```

```
class UserValidationService {

    public boolean validateUserCounterparty(UserRequest request) 
                   throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> result = userService.getUser(request.getUserName())
                .thenCompose(user -> userEntityService.getUserEntities(user.getUserId()))
                .thenCompose(userEntities -> validate(userEntities, request.getUserEntities()));

        Boolean validationStatus = result.get();
        if (!validationStatus) {
            log.error("Validation failed for user name {}", request.getUserName());
        }
        return validationStatus;
    }
}
```

And the test case is written as

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserValidationServiceTest {

    @Mock
    UserService userService;

    @Mock
    UserEntityService userEntityService;

    @InjectMocks
    UserValidationService userValidationService;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void validateUser() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<User> userFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        CompletableFuture<List<UserEntity>> userEntityFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

        Mockito.doReturn(userFuture).when(userService).getUser(anyString());
        Mockito.doReturn(userEntityFuture).when(userEntityService).getUserEntities(anyLong());

        UserRequest request = UserRequest.builder()
                .userName("admin")
                .userEntities(List.of("US", "ASIA", "EUROPE")).build();


        boolean result = validationService.validateUserCounterparty(request);
        assertTrue(result);

    }
}
```

On executing this test, it goes into infinite loop and never stops. I guess its because the completable future is not returning but I dont have enough knowledge on how to prevent it.

What modification should I do to prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your test method you're creating `CompletableFuture` instances using `new`. [JavaDoc states](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html):

> public CompletableFuture()
>
> Creates a new incomplete CompletableFuture.

So the objects you're creating are never completing, that's why the test is running infinitely. It's not actually a loop, but waiting on a blocking operation to be finished, which never happens.

What you need to do is define a `CompletableFuture` that completes - immediately or after some time. The simplest way of doing that is by using [the static completedFuture() method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completedFuture(U)):

```java
CompletableFuture<User> userFuture =
        CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new User());
CompletableFuture<List<UserEntity>> userEntityFuture =
        CompletableFuture.completedFuture(List.of(new UserEntity()));
```

Thanks to that given objects are returned and the code can be executed fully. You can test errors in a similar way by using [the failedFuture() method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#failedFuture(java.lang.Throwable)).

---

I've created [a GitHub repo with a minimal reproducible example](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/blob/73332148/src/test/java/io/github/jonarzz/UserValidationServiceTest.java#L31) - the test presented there passes.

Comment: I modified the code but getting NPE now.


`CompletableFuture<User> userFuture = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(User.builder().build());

        CompletableFuture<List<UserEntity>> userEntityFuture = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(List.of(UserEntity.builder().build()));


Mockito.when(userService.getUser(anyString())).thenReturn(userFuture);
        

Mockito.when(userEntityService.getUserEntities(anyLong())).thenReturn(userEntityFuture);


validationService.validateUserCounterparty(request);`

Comment: Where is the NPE thrown? Did you set all values required to avoid NPE?

Comment: nvm... the NPE was happening because of `new User()`. after populating it, the code worked. thanks for the help

Comment: @Jonasz can you please look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76298136/null-value-is-populated-to-completablefuture-variable-and-method-within-completa . I did similar to your answer, but the value of CompletableFuture is null in main class.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue today.
@Jonasz's answer only works if you can mock the method in `getUserEntities()` and `getUser()`. But what if we have logics inside these methods and we still want unittest run through these methods.

My solution is to change behavior for `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` from async to sync by using static mock

```
mockStatic(CompletableFuture.class, invoca -> {
    if (invoca.getMethod().getName().equals("supplyAsync")) {
        Supplier<?> supplier = invoca.getArgument(0);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(supplier.get());
    }
    return invoca.callRealMethod();
});
```

With this solution, I can run code inside async block and generic it for all `CompletableFuture` types

To use Static mock, you need to enable mock-inline. https://davidvlijmincx.com/posts/mockito_mock_static_method/