# How to mock CompletableFuture in mockito

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, mockito

HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);

```
      CompletableFuture<JsonNode> requestCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture
              .supplyAsync(() -> restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, JsonNode.class)) 
              .thenApply((responseFutures) -> {
               return responseFutures.getBody();
              });
      JsonNode response= requestCompletableFuture.get();
```

i am trying to mock completable future but it giving not expected response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing CompletableFuture.supplyAsync with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73332148/testing-completablefuture-supplyasync-with-mockito)

Comment: Which part are you trying to mock and what do you actually want to test/assert?

Comment: restTemplate.exchange(baseUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, JsonNode.class) this part need to test

Comment: And why do you need to mock a CompletableFuture to test this method?